# Easiest way to fetch data where userid matches the userid from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

So i have a table called `job_opslag`, where company's job posts is stored.

I also have a table called `virksomheder`, where the company's information is stored (address etc).

So I want to fetch the data from `virksomheder` where `userid` matches the `job_opslag`'s userid, and then print it out.

What is the easiest way to do that?

Kind regards

Comment: Welcome. To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm not asking anyone to write code for me. I'm asking for clearing an doubt, since i'm lost there. Thank's :-)

Comment: Do you know SQL Join?

Comment: For future reference, the way to get a good response from SO is to at least show what you have tried, otherwise it looks like a _Do It For me question_

Comment: @RonnieOosting i know some of it :-)

Comment: Well, that is your answer. Do you need an example? And can you provide us your current query?

Comment: Ah! Well if you can come with an example, that could be awesome @RonnieOosting! - I don't have any current query, since it was just a question :D

Comment: Alright, hang on. Meanwhile please provide us some code/query you currently use.

Comment: It would be useful ... for someone to produce the code... if you showed us the schema for these 2 tables

Comment: use join query so you can get result

Comment: @2accbot I've wrote an example with explanation and documentation. I hope this will help you out. If you have questions, do not hesitate and ask away.

Comment: Hi 2accbot, did any of the answers helped you out with your code?

Answer (score 3):

The SQL you can do it with is the following:

```
select * from job_opslag j, virksomheder v
  where j.userid = v.userid;
```

Comment: Would have been a much better attempt at an answer if you had used a JOIN

Answer (score 3):

You can use join query

```
select * from job_opslag j JOIN virksomheder v ON j.userid=v.userid;
```

Comment: maybe both tables use primary key as "id" so "select *" is not a good option

Comment: yes but still if user want to add particular column  he can add right instead of * ?because he didn't mention which columns he want to display from both  tables

Answer (score 3):

Your query should look something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM job_opslag jo
LEFT JOIN virksomheder AS v ON jo.id = v.id
```

What you do to "echo that out" depends entirely on what you're doing and where you're calling it from.

Answer (score 3):

You can acquire this by using a SQL Join.

**Example:**

```
SELECT something
FROM first
LEFT JOIN second ON first.column_name = second.column_name;
// Now add your WHERE etc.
```

A beautiful **example** can be found here:

- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_left

**Documentation:**

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-optimization.html

Grab something to smoke/drink/eat and a couple of hours of your time. Once you get your hand into 'JOIN's your live will be much more fun. Joins are very use-/ and powerful. Related to the future once your skills improve, your database's and code are somewhat 'next level' expanded you might want to create a `relational database`.

Please search google on 'Relational Database MySQL', if you want to learn more about it.

Answer (score 2):

use can try something like:

```
SELECT job_opslag.[Field_names], virksomheder.[Field_names] FROM job_opslag
LEFT JOIN virksomheder ON virksomheder.[Your Foreign Key] = job_opslag.[Your Promary Key];
```

also, use can change Join type such as RIGHT JOIN or INNER JOIN according to your data flow

Comment: don't forget to add the comment if the answer is not useful. if you just mark down vote without comment then don't do it

Answer (score 2):

You can just use SQL join
to get information from both the tables.

```
select * from job_opslag a inner join  virksomheder b   on a.userid = b.userid
```

(If for every userid in job_opslag(a), there is a userid in virksomheder(b)
or if you want only those records which have userid in both the tables)

You can use left join when every userid in table a might not be present in table b or vice versa

```
Select * from job_opslag a left join virksomheder b   on a.userid = b.userid
```

(Here you will be all the records from table a even if there are no matches for the userid in table b)

Comment: What does this add to the answer set that has not already been given as answers

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass your required input user id here  $User_id
and write the following query, It will join those two tables and fetch the data.

mysqli_query() will prepare and execute the query , mysqli_fetch_array() will fetch the data from the executed query in array format.  Here $Conn refers to db connection.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($Conn,"select * FROM job_opslag a left join virksomheder b on b.userid  = a.userid where a.userid =". $User_id);

$Data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: `mysql_` Really! You really should be using PHP7, or 7.1 or 7.2 where this api is no longer supported

Comment: only use PDO or mysqli to secure the db queries